# Ansible error "failed to create temporary directory"

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use a jumpbox to reach my target VM on ansible.
I have the following file structure

```
play.yaml
hosts
  serverA
  serverB
  testServers/
    serverX
    serverY
    group_vars/
      all.yml
```

`server[X,Y]` host file contains

```
[serverType]
1.2.3.4
```

`all.yml` file under `hosts/testServers/` contain

```
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: key.priv
proxy_user: myServiceAccount
proxy_user_key: key.priv
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i {{ proxy_user_key }} -W %h:%p -q {{ proxy_user }}@{{ bastion_host }}
```

I have a ping module in `play.yaml`

```
- hosts: all  
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - action: ping
```

I run the following command

```
ansible-playbook -vvvv play.yaml -i hosts/testServers/serverX 
  -e ansible_ssh_user="$LDAP_USER" -e ansible_ssh_pass="$LDAP_PASS" 
  -e ansible_become_pass="$LDAP_PASS"
  -e bastion_host="$BASTION_NAME"
```

I get the following error

```
Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have
been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the
target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in
ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error
information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p
\"` echo /tmp `\"&& mkdir
/tmp/ansible-tmp-1626262883.727861-210-80403864334304 && echo
ansible-tmp-1626262883.727861-210-80403864334304=\"` echo
/tmp/ansible-tmp-1626262883.727861-210-80403864334304 `\" ),
exited with result 6
```

---

To consider

- the ssh_user has permissions to rwx permissions on /tmp
- the `remote_tmp` is set to `/tmp` in ansible.cfg
- the ssh configs are set correctly on the source VM and the keypairs are working as expected by following this tutorial https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2020/10/26/use-a-ssh-jump-host-with-ansible/

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to create a temporary directory on a target host might have several causes. First verify that $LDAP_USER can connect via $BASTION_NAME using $LDAP_PASS, that can be tested from a shell on the ansible control host.

If credentials are OK, and a manual login is successful then investigate the file and directory permissions. Multi-user use of the temporary directory's parent directory might be a cause. Or mount options on /tmp, or disk-space issues, or other trouble. Errno 6 (no such device) in your output, might point  to deeper trouble on that host, or in your assumptions about your bastion host.

The multi-user problem (for instance unprivileged become_user, or combining root login with normal user login) can be resolved by config:

```ini
[defaults]
remote_tmp = /var/tmp/${USER}/ansible
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran `ansible -m ping [hostname] -vvv` and the extra detailed output provided but the "-vvv" flag showed that the default password for the ansible user had expired and needed to be changed for the ssh connection to succeed. Simply logging on to the remote host and changing the password (`passwd [user]`) for the use worked for me.